# Authentication for an Embedded Signing Ceremony?

Tags: docusignapi

My signers will login to my app's authentication system. How should I set up DocuSign authentication so my signers can sign via an embedded signing ceremony?

Answer (score 0):

In this answer note the important distinction between the **sender** of the signing request (the envelope) and the **signer** of the agreement.

In your scenario, the **signer** does not have a DocuSign account (this is a common pattern--signers don't need DocuSign accounts).

Here are the suggested steps:

1. The envelope is sent by the sender. The sender can be an API program or via the DocuSign web application.
2. The **signer** logs into your web app. So you've *authenticated* the signer.
3. You need a DocuSign access token to obtain access to the signing ceremony. In this situation, the JWT OAuth flow is recommended. Your app can use the JWT flow to impersonate the sender and obtain an access token.
4. Your app uses the access token to obtain the URL for the signing ceremony for the signer.
5. Your app presents the signing ceremony to the user. The best is to redirect the web browser to the signing ceremony (and later redirect back). State information can be stored in many different ways. Second best is to open a new tab for the signing ceremony and then close it once the signer has signed. Worst is to use an iframe since DocuSign does not fully support iframes for signing.
6. The signer signs.
7. Your app continues....

Here's a [live example of opening the signing ceremony in a new tab](https://codepen.io/docusign/full/MWXPKJY). Note the use of an [intermediate html file](https://github.com/docusign/docusign.github.io/blob/master/jsfiddleDsResponse.html) (below) to notify the parent app that the signing ceremony has completed and the new tab can be closed.

```
    <script>
      const msg = {source: 'dsResponse', hash: window.location.hash || '',
        href: window.location.href || ''}
      if (window.opener) {
        window.opener.postMessage(msg, '*');
      } else {
        window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
      }
    </script>
```